# How do I get rid of this white space?

Tags: css, removing-whitespace

I'm creating a div where users can leave a review about a class. At the end of the reviews, there is going to be text: "Show More" that loads more reviews. However, there is this white space between the very last review and the "Show More" text. **How do I get rid of this?**

```css
/* font */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

/* end of font */

/* clear settings */

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}
/* end of clear settings */

/* courses.php */

#star_score {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #777;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  left: 265px;
}

  .Rating2, .Rating3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 125px;
  height: 25px;
  top: -41px;
  left: 180px;
}

.Rating2 {
  top: -24px;
  left: 130px;
}

.Rating3 {
  width: 75px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: -88px;
}

.Rating2 svg, .Rating3 svg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.Rating2 meter, .Rating3 meter {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #B6C2CC;
}
.Rating2 meter::-moz-meter-bar, .Rating3 meter::-moz-meter-bar {
  background: #FF7867;
}

.Rating2 meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value, .Rating2 meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value, .Rating2 meter::-webkit-meter-even-less-good-value, .Rating3 meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value, .Rating3 meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value, .Rating3 meter::-webkit-meter-even-less-good-value {
  background: #FF7867;
}

/* Reviews */

#course_reviews {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  background: white;
  width: 579px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: -20px
}

#review_text {
  font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#course_line2 {
  width: 610px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
  top: -38px;
  left: -15px;
}

#student_rating {
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
  width: 610px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#student_rating_img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 20px;
}

#student_username {
  color: #00698C;
  position: relative;
  top: -88px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 490px;
}

#student_date {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
}

#student_content {
  color: #0E0E0F;
  width: 490px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

#show_more {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
  width: 590px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#show_more:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#show_more_text {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  left: 10px;
}

/* End of Reviews */

/* end of courses.php */
```

```html
<?php

require "connect.php";

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Hacked Genius </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body id='course_body'>

<br> <br> <br>
  
    <!-- Reviews -->
    
    <!-- Top Part -->
    
      <div id='course_reviews'>
        <span id='review_text'> 2937 Reviews </span>
        <div class="Rating2">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 100">
            <defs>
              <path id="a" d="M0 0h500v100H0V0zm50 79L20.6 94.5l5.6-32.8L2.4 38.5l33-4.7L50 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L50 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L150 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L150 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L250 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L250 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L350 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L350 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L450 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L450 79z"/>
            </defs>
            <use fill="white" fill-rule="evenodd" xlink:href="#a"/>
          </svg>
        
          <meter min="0" max="5" value="4.28"></meter>
        </div>  <span id='star_score'> 4.7 </span>
        
        <div id='course_line2'></div>
        
        <!-- End of Top Part -->
        
        <!-- Student Part -->
        
        <div id='student_rating'>
          <img src='https://cdnil1.fiverrcdn.com/photos/31519238/small/1459227_10151771032542219_1796077253_n.jpg?1461604087' id='student_rating_img'>
          
          <!-- Student Usernames -->
          
          <div id='student_username'> Matthew Malan <span id='student_date'> 1 day ago </span> <br>
          <span id='student_content'> Outstanding Experience! </span>
          
          <!-- Student Rating -->
            <div class="Rating3">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 100">
            <defs>
              <path id="a" d="M0 0h500v100H0V0zm50 79L20.6 94.5l5.6-32.8L2.4 38.5l33-4.7L50 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L50 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L150 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L150 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L250 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L250 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L350 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L350 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L450 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L450 79z"/>
            </defs>
            <use fill="white" fill-rule="evenodd" xlink:href="#a"/>
          </svg>
        
          <meter min="0" max="5" value="4"></meter>
        </div>
          <!-- End of Student Rating -->
          
          </div>
        
        <!-- End of Student Usernames & Stars -->
          
        </div>
        
              <!-- End of Student Part -->
              
              
               <!-- Student Part -->
        
        <div id='student_rating'>
          <img src='https://cdnil1.fiverrcdn.com/photos/31519238/small/1459227_10151771032542219_1796077253_n.jpg?1461604087' id='student_rating_img'>
          
          <!-- Student Usernames -->
          
          <div id='student_username'> Matthew Malan <span id='student_date'> 1 day ago </span> <br>
          <span id='student_content'> Outstanding Experience! </span>
          
          <!-- Student Rating -->
            <div class="Rating3">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 100">
            <defs>
              <path id="a" d="M0 0h500v100H0V0zm50 79L20.6 94.5l5.6-32.8L2.4 38.5l33-4.7L50 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L50 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L150 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L150 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L250 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L250 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L350 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L350 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L450 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L450 79z"/>
            </defs>
            <use fill="white" fill-rule="evenodd" xlink:href="#a"/>
          </svg>
        
          <meter min="0" max="5" value="4"></meter>
        </div>
          <!-- End of Student Rating -->
          
          </div>
        
        <!-- End of Student Usernames & Stars -->
          
        </div>
        
              <!-- End of Student Part -->
              
              
               <!-- Student Part -->
        
        <div id='student_rating'>
          <img src='https://cdnil1.fiverrcdn.com/photos/31519238/small/1459227_10151771032542219_1796077253_n.jpg?1461604087' id='student_rating_img'>
          
          <!-- Student Usernames -->
          
          <div id='student_username'> Matthew Malan <span id='student_date'> 1 day ago </span> <br>
          <span id='student_content'> Outstanding Experience! </span>
          
          <!-- Student Rating -->
            <div class="Rating3">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 100">
            <defs>
              <path id="a" d="M0 0h500v100H0V0zm50 79L20.6 94.5l5.6-32.8L2.4 38.5l33-4.7L50 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L50 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L150 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L150 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L250 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L250 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L350 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L350 79zm100 0l-29.4 15.5 5.6-32.8-23.8-23.2 33-4.7L450 4l14.7 29.8 33 4.7-24 23.2 5.7 32.8L450 79z"/>
            </defs>
            <use fill="white" fill-rule="evenodd" xlink:href="#a"/>
          </svg>
        
          <meter min="0" max="5" value="4"></meter>
        </div>
          <!-- End of Student Rating -->
          
          </div>
        
        <!-- End of Student Usernames & Stars -->
          
        </div>
        
              <!-- End of Student Part -->

              
              <!-- Show More -->
              
              <div id='show_more'> <span id='show_more_text'> Show More </span> </div>
              
              <!-- End of Show More -->
              
        
      </div>
    
      
      
      
    <!-- End of Reviews -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I start, I notice that all your `student-rating` divs have the same ID value. Please note that this is invalid HTML as you shouldn't have multiple elements on a page with the same ID. You should use `class="student-rating"` instead of `id=`. For the rest of this answer I'll assume that you've done this. Note that my code below will only work if you do this.

The main problem you have is caused by you positioning all the elements within the review div with a negative `top`.

Although you've got them all positioned well relative to each other, the actual `student-rating` div ends up with a big gap at the bottom that can't easily be closed up.

You also have an extra gap caused by `margin-bottom:10px`, which makes the white space even bigger.

There is a quick and dirty way to solve this, There is also a more difficult solution that will end up with your code being better overall.

First, the quick solution:

Firstly, move the 'Show more' element outside of the `course-reviews` element, so that the code below affects the last review, and not the show more button. Then, add the following code:

```
.student-rating:last-of-type {
  margin-botton:-15px;
}
```

This will override the bottom margin on the last review, and should close up the gap nicely. Feel free to adjust the exact value if you need to, but -15px looks about right to me.

This solution is quite 'hacky'; it's not good code, but it works with what you've got. The better solution, below, would be to fix your existing code so that a hack like this isn't necessary.

How do you do that? Well, it's too long to justify putting in an answer here, but in short, you need to get rid of all those negative `top` values you've got in the CSS for the elements within `student-rating`. Start with the biggest one and set it to zero, then adjustall the others by the same amount. The layout should remain the same visually for the rating block, but it should make it easier to get it positioned properly. I notice you've also got some negative `left` values too. Those should probably be removed as well while you're at it.

My guess is that you've added the negative top and left values in order to compensate for other layout glitches, so those will probably need to be resolved as well once you've done that. But this time without using negative positioning!